# JAVA | Thread.sleep() error / Nullpointer

Tags: java

I am sorry I am beginner in java. For my little adventure game that I am working on, I want to add an delay in my gameLoop actully for testing my graphics.

The problem is I have an loop where the things get printet/paintet on screen (call it how u want :D). When I do that usual I have no problems, but when I add a Thread.sleep (with throws or try&catch) I get an NullPointerExeption somewhere in my program wich has nothing to do with that part here is my code:

GUI CLASS:

```
package xxx.yyy.zzz;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JPanel {

private JFrame frame;
private Control ctr;

final int objectSize = 10;

public GUI() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(this);
    ctr = new Control(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(int x = 0; x < ctr.getScreenSizeX(); x = x + objectSize) {
        for(int y = 0; y < ctr.getScreenSizeY(); y = y + objectSize) {
            g.setColor(ctr.getScreen(x/objectSize, y/objectSize));
            g.drawRect(x, y, objectSize, objectSize);
            g.fillRect(x, y, objectSize, objectSize);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

CONTROL CLASS:

```
package xxx.yyy.zzz;

import java.awt.Color;

public class Control {

private GUI gui;
private Level l1;

private Color[][] screen;
private Player player;

private final int screenSizeX = 400;
private final int screenSizeY = 300;

public Control(GUI pGUI) {
    gui = pGUI;
    l1 = new Level(400, 30, true);
    screen = new Color[screenSizeX][screenSizeY];
    player = new Player(Color.WHITE);

    gameLoop();
}

private void gameLoop() {

    print(l1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        player.move(1);
        print(l1);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);                      //here is my problem!
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private void print(Level pL) {
    if(pL.getSizeX() > 40 || pL.getSizeX() > 40) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 30; y++) {
                screen[x][y] = pL.getObjectColor(x + (player.getX() - 10), 
y);
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 30; y++) {
                screen[x][y] = pL.getObjectColor(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    gui.repaint();
}

public Color getScreen(int x, int y) {
    return screen[x][y];
}

public int getScreenSizeX() {
    return screenSizeX;
}

public int getScreenSizeY() {
    return screenSizeY;
}

}
```

I censored my package xD

Thank you for your replies, sorry I am not familiar with game programming and programming beginner!

EDIT: My Error Log:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.zeptosi.snogg.GUI.paintComponent(GUI.java:31)
...

Comment: to see a change in my graphics it is for testing purpose

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Yet another NullPointerException question. Please search on the exception first before asking as these get asked time and again. Then do what the duplicate question answers tell you to, starting at `GUI.java:31`, line 31 of the GUI class.

Comment: Don't use Thread.sleep for your Game loop. Instead use a Swing Timer.